# Tikz nested nodes position

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

(Edited as suggested)

I have following code involving connected nodes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    P(t) =
        \tikz[baseline]{\node[fill=blue!50, anchor=base] (t1) {$
            \epsilon_{0}\chi^{(1)}E(t)
        $};}
        +
        \tikz[baseline]{\node[fill=red!50, anchor=base] (t2) {$
             \tikz[baseline]{\node[fill=green!25, anchor=base] (t21) {$
                \epsilon_{0}\chi^{(2)}E^{2}(t)
             $};}
            +
             \tikz[baseline]{\node[fill=yellow!25, anchor=base] (t22) {$
                \epsilon_{0}\chi^{(3)}E^{3}(t)
             $};}
            + \cdots
        $};}
\end{equation}
\begin{itemize}
    \item \tikz[baseline]{\node[anchor=base] (n1) {Linear};}
    \item \tikz[baseline]{\node[anchor=base] (n2) {Nonlinear};}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item \tikz[baseline]{\node[anchor=base] (n21) {2. order};}
        \item \tikz[baseline]{\node[anchor=base] (n22) {3. order};}
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
    \path[blue, ->, line width=1pt] (n1.north east) edge[out=45, in=-90]     (t1.south);
     \path[red, ->, line width=1pt] (n2.north east) edge[out=45, in=-90] (t2.south);
     \path[red, ->, dashed, line width=0.75pt] (n21.east) edge[out=0, in=-90] (t21.south);
     \path[red, ->, dashed, line width=0.75pt] (n22.east) edge[out=0, in=-90] (t22.south);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This code gives me following output, where is some offset in x coordinate inside of node t2:
[image: Output of given code]

If I comment out the creation of this node (t2), the dashed arrows now pointing in correct locations:
[image: Now without 'parent' node (t2)]

What I want is the first figure (red solid line and red fill) with dashed arrows pointing at positions as shown in the second figure. Is there a way how to do this?

Thanks a lot for any suggestions

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to help you. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Nesting TikZ pictures = bad idea. Options are inherited. Please make your code compilable as @Jubobs explained or add a picture of how your output should look like. If you want to fill the area behind a node you can use the `backgrounds` library and/or the `pgfonlayer` environment.

Comment: I updated the post little bit, sorry about that. Hope it is better now.

Comment: Have you compiled twice? [It looks good to me.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/7RDUO.png) You might be interested in the [`hf-tikz`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hf-tikz) package.

Comment: Ha, my bad! I used latex instead of pdflatex. With pdflatex it works just fine. Thanks.

Comment: I really think that your second figure is clearer.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem that does not exist if correctly compiled with pdf(La)TeX.